# SpringBoot @WebMvcTest and @MockBean not working as expected

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-mvc, spring-boot

It seems that `@WebMvcTest` and `@MockBean` are not working as expected. Maybe I'm missing something... I have a controller with some dependencies I'm mocking with `@MockBean`, but the application fails to start because it cannot find another bean that I think should not be required in this case.

CONTROLLER:

```
@RestController
public class ExchangeRateStoreController {
    private AddExchangeRate addExchangeRate;
    private AddExchangeRateRequestAdapter addExchangeRateRequestAdapter;
    private GetExchangeRate getExchangeRate;
    private GetExchangeRateRequestAdapter getExchangeRateRequestAdapter;

    @Autowired
    public ExchangeRateStoreController(ExchangeRateRepository exchangeRateRepository, ExchangeRateDateValidator exchangeRateDateValidator, ExchangeRateView exchangeRateView) {
        addExchangeRate = new AddExchangeRate(exchangeRateRepository, exchangeRateDateValidator);
        addExchangeRateRequestAdapter = new AddExchangeRateRequestAdapter();
        getExchangeRate = new GetExchangeRate(exchangeRateView);
        getExchangeRateRequestAdapter = new GetExchangeRateRequestAdapter();
    }

    @PostMapping
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public void create(@RequestBody AddExchangeRateRequest addExchangeRateRequest) {
        addExchangeRate.execute(addExchangeRateRequestAdapter.toCommand(addExchangeRateRequest));
    }
}
```

TEST:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(ExchangeRateStoreController.class)
public class ExchangeRateStoreControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;  
    @MockBean
    ExchangeRateRepository exchangeRateRepository;
    @MockBean
    ExchangeRateDateValidator exchangeRateDateValidator;
    @MockBean
    ExchangeRateView exchangeRateView;

    @Test
    public void givenValidExchangeRateCommand_whenCreate_thenOK() throws Exception {
        String validRequestBody = "{\"from\":\"EUR\",\"to\":\"USD\",\"amount\":1.2345,\"date\":\"2018-11-19\"}";

        doNothing().when(exchangeRateDateValidator).validate(any());
        doNothing().when(exchangeRateRepository).save(any());

        mvc.perform(post("/").content(validRequestBody).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().isCreated());
    }
```

APPLICATION:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories("com...exchangerate.store.infrastructure.persistence")
@EntityScan("com...exchangerate.store.infrastructure.persistence")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com...exchangerate.store.infrastructure", "com...exchangerate.store.application"} )
public class ExchangeRateStoreApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ExchangeRateStoreApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

And the error I get when run the test:

> APPLICATION FAILED TO START
>
> ---
>
> Description:
>
> A component required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could
>   not be found.
>
> Action:
>
> Consider defining a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' in your
>   configuration.

But, as you can see, `entityManagerFactory` is not a controller's dependency. So, why is the test trying to load this bean? I'm mocking all the controller dependencies, so I think it shouldn't do this.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem's caused by your use of `@EnableJpaRepositories` on your application's main class. By placing it on the main class, you're indicating that JPA repositories must always be enabled, irrespective of which particular slice of functionality you're trying to test.

You can fix your problem by doing one of the following:

- Move `@EnableJpaRepositores` and `@EntityScan` onto a separate JPA-specific configuration class
- Remove `@EnableJpaRepositories` and `@EntityScan` and rely on the auto-configured defaults. For this to work, your repositories and entities will have to be in a sub-package of your main class's package.

There's some more information about this in Spring Boot's [reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-detecting-config) where it says the following:

> If you use a test annotation to test a more specific slice of your application, you should avoid adding configuration settings that are specific to a particular area on the main method’s application class.

In this particular case, the configuration setting that is specific to a particular area is `@EnableJpaRepositories`.

Comment: Many thanks @andy-wilkinson!! Your answer goes right to the point. It definitely solved my problem. However, I'm facing a new related issue. Could you please take a look at this question I've just posted? -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53545831/spring-boot-mockbean-estrange-behaviour 
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score -1):

Hello there is an excellent link on this post: [EntityManagerFactory not found in SpringBoot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45350546/entitymanagerfactory-not-found-in-springboot)

You could check your spring boot jpa integration and have some good tips to set up your environment.